# Windows forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Создаю маленькую программу на C#. При запуске этой программы,пользователь может менять её ширину и высоту. Как сделать так , что бы пользователь во время использывания программы не мог менять её высоту и ширину ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство FormBorderStyle поменяй на FixedDialog
вроде так, мб немного отличаются названия

Ну или задай минимальный и максимальный размер формы одинаковый)

Comment: Там же вид формы изменится?

Comment: нет вроде, только иконка пропадает